# Google script giving bogus values on reading spreadsheet with imported data

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Recently I noticed that a script which reads a range of a destination spreadsheet which contains data imported from a source spreadsheet spreadsheet (Using IMPORTRANGE function) is occasionally (but not always) returning bogus values. To check for errors I ran the scripton an hourly trigger and got the following result.

```
  Timestamp           Value of cell B4

  3/14/2018 19:46:15    Biochemistry
  3/14/2018 20:16:14    Biochemistry
  3/14/2018 22:07:32    #ERROR!
  3/15/2018 0:07:32     #ERROR!
  3/15/2018 2:07:34     #ERROR!
  3/15/2018 4:07:31     #ERROR!
  3/15/2018 6:07:34     #ERROR!
  3/15/2018 8:07:22     Biochemistry
  3/15/2018 10:07:22    Biochemistry
  3/15/2018 12:07:09    Biochemistry
  3/15/2018 14:07:32    Biochemistry
  3/15/2018 16:07:33    #ERROR!
  3/15/2018 16:20:40    Biochemistry
  3/15/2018 18:07:23    Biochemistry
  3/15/2018 20:07:28    Biochemistry
  3/15/2018 22:07:23    Biochemistry
  3/16/2018 0:07:22     Biochemistry
  3/16/2018 2:07:34     #ERROR!
  3/16/2018 4:07:33     #ERROR!
  3/16/2018 6:07:33     #ERROR!
  3/16/2018 8:07:33     #ERROR!
  3/16/2018 10:07:33    #ERROR!
  3/16/2018 12:07:22    Biochemistry
  3/16/2018 14:07:22    Biochemistry
  3/16/2018 16:07:33    #ERROR!
  3/16/2018 18:07:24    Biochemistry
  3/16/2018 20:07:35    #ERROR!
  3/16/2018 22:07:24    Biochemistry
  3/17/2018 0:07:23     Biochemistry
```

The script reads the cell "B4" of the destination sheet which has the following formula '=IF(MONTH(TODAY())<6,IMPORTRANGE("SOURCE SHEET1 ID","SHEET1!B4:B"),IMPORTRANGE("SOURCE SHEET2 ID","SHEET1!B4:B")'.

When I open the  destination spreadsheet to check errors, everything looks fine with all the data imported as expected. I also made a copy of the destination spreadsheet and tried the script on the new spreadsheet, but the result is same.

What could be the problem?

Comment: The error value usually comes with help text. I suggest reviewing it. Timeouts are very possible. If you have the ability to write scripts, you may as well simply read the value of the target sheet in the script, and serialize it as appropriate

Comment: I am aware that the error values have help text, but for that I need to open the spreadsheet, and as soon as I do that the data loads as expected and there is no error. I did not get what you meant by timeout, please elaborate. The above log is actually the value of the target sheet read by a script every two hour. The script reads the value of cell B4 of the target sheet and saves it in another spreadsheet.

Comment: a timeout would occur when the function takes more time to respond with an answer than Google cares to spend waiting. You can try including a `SpreadsheetApp.flush()` call before reading your values, but that's unlikely to do anything. The better solution is to query the results in the script directly from the respective spreadsheets if their values are needed in the script.

Comment: I tried several permutations and combinations but the issue is still there. The problem seems to be associated with IMPORTRANGE() enclosed in IF condition with MONTH(TODAY()) formula. Removing the IF condition solves the problem.